# Googl colab сбрасывает обучение

Tags: google-colaboratory

1318: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use zero_division parameter to control this behavior.
_warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
может ли такой ворнинг вырубить выполнение кода на колабе
задолбался, через 8 часов 45 минут колаб останавливает сессию
колаб-про платный, должен робить 24 часа
кто с колабом дружен и обучал сетки там?

Comment: Ну это вроде не связано. Тут пишут, что у вас в предикте не получается каких-то лейблов, которые есть в тесте. Проверьте ваши данные. Ну либо правда такой набор данных подобрался. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47285662/8324991

Comment: А так ну слишком мало инфы, чтобы что-то советовать. Я бы для начала попробовал поменьше выборку данных взять и на них потренироваться, чтобы весь процесс прогнать, а потом уже масштабировать.

Comment: Да, я понял, что в предикте нет каких-то меток. Но это не должно вырубать код, верно? А что там проверять в данных? Данные предоставлены заказчиком.

Comment: Ну да, это вроде варнинг просто. А в логах же колаб что-то пишет? Может память кончилась, например. А так то ну вы не можете разве взять не все данные, а случайную выборку из них сделать, ну там 10%, например? Просто чтобы отладить процесс.

Comment: Я с колабом постольку поскольку, заказчик пока решил обойтись малой кровью и деньгами, поэтому колаб, т.к. обучение модели на нормальном сервере обойдется в 3-4тр, а у него их порядка 30 будет. Просто я не смог найти, где эти логи в колабе смотреть.

Comment: Ну например сверху меню "Среда выполнения" -> "Показать журналы среды выполнения". Если среда крашилась или что-то такое, то вроде там должны быть про это записи.

Comment: Да вроде там мне ничего не показалось подозрительным, но я не очень в этом разбираюсь